# Parsing date and time with the new java.time.DateTimeFormatter

Tags: parsing, date, time, java-8

I have a date of this type: 2004-12-31 23:00:00-08 but no one of the patterns i know and i have used from the documentation is working. I thought it should something like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX" but it isn't working.

Comment: please write your code here

Comment: What should "-08" be? Time offest?

Comment: You should try using yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZ" or "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXX". There are two time zones RFC and ISO. Also, is there any reason why the timezone is not -0800, but -08?

Comment: Can you let us know what are your expection in terms of timestamp i.e. how should it be post formatting?

Comment: For me, the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX" works fine. What problems do you have?

Comment: I get something like 01st Jan 2005 becuse you are 8 hours behind the GTM time i suppose? Is that what you expect? The code that does it is [here](http://ideone.com/7ysVpg). Are you using Java8?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The OP explicitly asks for Java-8-`DateTimeFormatter` not `SimpleDateFormat`. Latter one can indeed parse the given input.

Comment: @MenoHochschild What makes you think that I didn't use Java 8 classes? I tested it with `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX")` and that works!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Ah sorry and excuse, I have mistaken a link from the comment below yours. Yes, you are right, I have tested again all variants: Only one letter X can parse, but not XX or XXX (there is a small bug as described in my answer). If you write your comment as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Nothing to excuse. It's ok. You should update your answer accordingly. I also think, it could be a problem with previous minor version of the JDK. Maybe updating Java will resolve that issue.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Have updated my answer pointing to your comment. Updating to a newer Java-version will unfortunately not help (otherwise it would also have been marked as resolved in the Oracle bug tracker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for you, but this is a known bug and was already reported in January 2014. According to the [bug log](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8032051) a possible solution is deferred.

A simple workaround avoiding alternative external libraries is text preprocessing. That means: Before you parse the text you just append the prefix ":00". Example:

```
String input = "2004-12-31 23:00:00-08";
String zero = ":00";
if (input.charAt(input.length() - 3) == ':') {
  zero = "";
}
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
  ZonedDateTime.parse(
    input + zero, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX"));
System.out.println(zdt);
// output: 2004-12-31T23:00-08:00
```

**UPDATE due to debate with @Seelenvirtuose:**

As long as you ONLY have offsets with just hours but without minute part then the pattern "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX" will solve your problem, too (as @Seelenvirtuose has correctly stated in his comment).

But if you have to process a list of various strings with mixed offsets like "-08", "Z" or "+05:30" (latter is India standard time) then you should usually apply the pattern containing three XXX. But this currently fails (have verified it by testing in last version of Java-8). So in this case you still have to do text preprocessing and/or text analysis.